# How to view node_modules dependency tree?

Tags: npm, node-modules

How do I view the dependency graph of a npm-based project?

I tried [Madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) but it ignores node_modules.

Answer (score 34):

Use `npm list -a`, e.g.

```
$ npm list -a
my-app@1.0.0 C:\Dev\my-app
+-- @types/node@9.6.6
+-- @types/react@16.3.13
| `-- csstype@2.4.1
+-- @types/react-dom@16.0.5
| +-- @types/node@9.6.6 deduped
| `-- @types/react@16.3.13 deduped
+-- react@16.3.2
| +-- fbjs@0.8.16
| | +-- core-js@1.2.7
| | +-- isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1
| | | +-- node-fetch@1.7.3
| | | | +-- encoding@0.1.12
| | | | | `-- iconv-lite@0.4.21
| | | | |   `-- safer-buffer@2.1.2
| | | | `-- is-stream@1.1.0
| | | `-- whatwg-fetch@2.0.4
| | +-- loose-envify@1.3.1 deduped
| | +-- object-assign@4.1.1 deduped
| | +-- promise@7.3.1
| | | `-- asap@2.0.6
| | +-- setimmediate@1.0.5
| | `-- ua-parser-js@0.7.17
| +-- loose-envify@1.3.1
| | `-- js-tokens@3.0.2
| +-- object-assign@4.1.1
| `-- prop-types@15.6.1
|   +-- fbjs@0.8.16 deduped
|   +-- loose-envify@1.3.1 deduped
|   `-- object-assign@4.1.1 deduped
+-- react-dom@16.3.2
| +-- fbjs@0.8.16 deduped
| +-- loose-envify@1.3.1 deduped
| +-- object-assign@4.1.1 deduped
| `-- prop-types@15.6.1 deduped
`-- typescript@2.8.3
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `npm install` fails, and I want to use it to debug `npm install` by understanding why a dependency is being installed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
npm-remote-ls
```

**Or**

You can check http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/npm-remote-ls

This site allows you to view a packages tree as a node graph in 2D or 3D.